# POST request to ProBasketballAPI.com using Javascript

Tags: javascript, post, networking

I am trying to get data from the ProBasketballAPI.com API. The docs state the following:

'To make calls to the ProBasketball API, you must make a POST request to the specified URL. In this request you must pass along your API key, and that is it. You now have access to the API!

Of course you can pass along arguments other than just your API key, in fact, it is encouraged that you do so. It will help narrow down data that will be returned.

All responses will be in the JSON format.'

I am trying to pass the api_key as an argument as it states like this.

```
const options = {
    'api_key': JSON.stringify(api_key),
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};

const x = fetch('https://probasketballapi.com/players', options);

x.then((response) => {
    const data = response.json();
    data.then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
    })
})
```

But I receive the following error from the api,

```
{ errors: [ 'The api key field is required.' ] }
```

I have read the documentation but I can not figure it out. The documentation can be found at https://probasketballapi.com/docs/authentication

Comment: What is the value of `JSON.stringify(api_key)` ?  What does it show when written to the console?  `console.log("API Key is " + JSON.stringify(api_key));`

Comment: it console logs : API Key is "apiKEY IS HERE"

Comment: Do you have an API Key?  It looks like you are using example code, and you need to purchase/acquire an API Key ..

Comment: Have you tested out your request in Postman?

Comment: Yes I have an api key, I just added the sample code because I am not going to share It.